# Server doesn't seem to receive Client message ANDROID

Tags: android, sockets, client

I am working on a chat client application and I have made a server. I managed to make the client connect to the server, but then when I send a message to the server, there's no reaction from the server.

Here is the part of the code of my server that is not working

```
class ClientConnect implements Runnable {


private DataInputStream in = null;
private DataOutputStream out = null;
Socket client;

ClientConnect(Socket client) {

    try {
        this.client = client;
       /* obtain an input stream to this client ... */
        in = new DataInputStream (client.getInputStream());

        /* ... and an output stream to the same client */
        setOut(new DataOutputStream (client.getOutputStream()));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run() {

    String msg, response;
    ChatServerProtocol protocol = new ChatServerProtocol(this);

    try {

        while (true) {

            if (in.available() > 0){
                msg = in.readUTF();
                response = protocol.process(msg);
                getOut().writeBytes("SERVER: " + response);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    } finally {

        // The connection is closed for one reason or another       
        try {
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void sendMsg(String msg) {
    try {
        getOut().writeBytes(msg);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public DataOutputStream getOut() {
    return out;
}

public void setOut(DataOutputStream out) {
    this.out = out;
}
}
```

And here is the client :

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String response = null;

    EditText nicknameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nicknameField);
    EditText passwordField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordField);

    nickname = nicknameField.getText().toString();
    password = passwordField.getText().toString();

    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.signin:           

            new SendMessage(this).execute("SIGNUP " + nickname + " " + password );

            break;
        case R.id.signup:

            new SendMessage(this).execute("SIGNUP " + nickname + " " + password );

            break;  
    }
}

private String onPostExecuteSendMessage() {
    return null;
}

public void showMessage(String response) {

    Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(response);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

}

public void getClientSocket(Socket client) {

    this.client = client;
    try {
        out = new DataOutputStream (client.getOutputStream());
        in = new DataInputStream (client.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public DataOutputStream getOut() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.out;
}

public DataInputStream getIn() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.in;
}

public void goMenuChat() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuChatActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Also I used an Asynctask to send message from the client :

```
    package client.chatclient;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;

    public class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    private static final String msg_OK = "OK";
    private static final String msg_NICK_IN_USE = "NICK IN USE";
    private static final String msg_UNKNOWN_CMD = "UNKNOWN CMD";
    private static final String msg_INVALID = "INVALID COMMAND";
    private static final String msg_SEND_FAILED = "FAILED TO SEND";
    private static final String msg_INCORRECT_IDS = "INCORRECT IDS";
    private static final String msg_DISCONNECT = "DISCONNECT";

    private WeakReference<MainActivity> activity;
    private String message;
    private String response = "";
    private DataOutputStream out;
    private DataInputStream in;

    public SendMessage(MainActivity act){
        super();
        activity = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(act);

    }

   protected String doInBackground(String... message) {
       this.message = message[0];
       this.out =  activity.get().getOut();
       this.in = activity.get().getIn();
       try {
          out.writeBytes(this.message);
       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }


       response = convertStreamToString(this.in);

       return response;
   }



   protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

       if ((response == msg_INCORRECT_IDS) || (response == msg_NICK_IN_USE)){
            activity.get().showMessage(response);
        }
        else if (response == msg_OK){
            activity.get().goMenuChat();

        }

   }

    private static String convertStreamToString(DataInputStream in) {
        /*
         * To convert the InputStream to String we use the
         * BufferedReader.readLine() method. We iterate until the BufferedReader
         * return null which means there's no more data to read. Each line will
         * appended to a StringBuilder and returned as String.
         */     

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return sb.toString();
    }

    }
```

I send my message from the client by clicking on a button then it goes to the SendMessage class, and send the message to the server and normally the server should receive my message in the loop "while (true)..." and sends back a response according to the protocol that I've implemented.

I really don't know what is wrong. If you know how to solve this issue or have some solutions, please tell me ! If you want more details, ask me ! :)

Thank you very much !

EDIT:

I instanciated my ClientConnect here

```
public class ChatServer {


private static int port = 8080; 

public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port); /* start listening on the port */
    System.out.println( "Listening on "+ server );

    Socket client = null;

    while(true) {
        try {
            client = server.accept();
            System.out.println( "Connection from " + client );
            /* start a new thread to handle this client */
            Thread t = new Thread(new ClientConnect(client));
            t.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.err.println("Accept failed.");
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
            server.close();
        }   
    }


}
```

}

EDIT: I found where the problem is. I put some log() statements as you said

```
   log.d(null,"beforeconvert")
    try {
        log.d(null,"convert")
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.d(null,"errorconvert")
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

After that in logcat, it just shows "beforeconvert". I don't really know what the problem is ? **while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) is surely the problem. When I use the debugger step by step in eclipse, it stops at this line and doesn't even go inside the loop.**

EDIT : I REALLY don't know why, but when I quit the emulator when running my app, it shows everything.

```
Listening on ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=8080]
Connection from Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=56646,localport=8080]
client connected
msg received
error !
SIGNUP Nickname Password  

SIGNUP Nickname Password  

msg converted
OK
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at server.ClientConnect.convertStreamToString(ChatServer.java:357)
    at server.ClientConnect.run(ChatServer.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

Comment: Add some Log() statements so you/we can see how far the server comes. Put them also in the catch blocks. Show how you instantiate/call ClientConnect.

Comment: My problem might come from                                         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {                             did I use it the method readLine properly ?

Comment: Your server isn't sending anything. So there is nothing for your client to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are writing data to output stream in the end you need to flush

this.out.flush();

I think this is why the data is not sent and received

Hope that helps.

Edit:

Let me try to explain in general idea..

When you are opening a socket you have a connection to another machince.

So the

```
in.available();
```

and

```
socket.accpet();
```

Should work.. once you are writing into outputstream you must flush in order to see the data(or close, i think it flushes before it get closed).

Anyway i attach a link to an example.. You should try this one, Or look at parts you have problem with..

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

Comment: thank you for your response, I added this on both my server but it does not work. My server actually receives the message but get stuck at this line  **while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)** for some reason..

Comment: Ok, You still need to use flush after writing.. After you write flush will be the action to send the bytes you have written..
After sending you are waiting for inputStream to write to you...
Because you never use flush it will never send the data and this is why it is waiting.. because it doesn't get the transmit.

Don't know how your server get the data..This sound weird.. Flush is must to be used.. And also suggest to close in/out output stream

Comment: Ok for the flush :)  my server receives the data in this loop **while (true) {

            if (in.available() > 0)**...  it enters in the if statements when i click on the button, so it works until there. And is it mandatory to close in and out stream ? because I want to use them many times since it is a chat application.

Comment: But can you see this lines? It receive the string?
msg = in.readUTF();
response = protocol.process(msg);

Comment: Nope. I replaced in.readUTF() by convertStreamToString(in). and I couldn't see the msg and the response. I just added something on my post, please check.

Comment: I edited my post.. Look at the link. It is same thing you need..You can try even copy paste it will be easy